# Displaying data in a jTable

Tags: java, jtable

I have a class A with a jButton, when i press it I need a class B to instantiate and show a jTable with data.

The problem is that I have only been able to display the data if the user presses a second jButton located in class B - which I don't want -. What I need is the data to be already loaded in the jTable when it is shown.

Any ideas on how to show the data just by clicking the first button Class A)?

Comment: post the code pls

Comment: try posting your question with code will help users to understand your problem more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor of class B to load data to jTable, so what you need to do is instantiate class B through the button click.Else you can create jTable as static member of class B, so you can set data to jTable through the button click, so you dont need to use second button which is located in class B.